# Mocking HttpServletResponse and passing it to ServletActionContext - And get the response object

Tags: java, servlets, junit, struts2, mockito

I have the following code.

```
    HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    System.out.println("Response: " + response); // Prints "Mock for HttpServletResponse, hashCode: 2051435028"

    ServletActionContext.setResponse(response);
    System.out.println("Get Response: " + ServletActionContext.getResponse()); // Prints null.
```

`ServletActionContext.getResponse())` prints null while `response` is not null when setting.

How do I get the response object?

Mockito, Struts2, JUnit

Comment: Are you sure that `setResponse()` and `getResponse()` work correctly? If calling the get method does not return the instanced that was provided to the set method then there is something wrong.

Comment: I am printing `response` object before passing it to ServletActionContext and it prints. But when I call ServletActionContext.getResponse(), it returns null.

Comment: Yeah, so the problem is inside `setResponse()` or `getResponse()`, it is not related to Mockito.

Comment: @AdamSiemion thanks. I posted the workaround in the answer. Please check.

Comment: Good, I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I got a workaround. For others help...

I checked the code of `getResponse()`

```
public static HttpServletResponse getResponse() {
    return (HttpServletResponse) ActionContext.getContext().get(HTTP_RESPONSE);
}
```

So I am already passing a mocked `context` object to the `ServletActionContext`. So before passing it, I am mocking the context call like this.

```
actionContext = mock(ActionContext.class);
when(actionContext.get(org.apache.struts2.StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE)).thenReturn(response);
```

Now it works!